# Parallel programming for two functions of different obj but same class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiprocessing

As I wrote in the title I'm trying to let two unrelated functions work in parallel. The functions are from two different objects of the same class. Here is an example below:

```
class Converter:
     def __init__(self):
        pass

     def myfunc(self):
        do_something

if __name__ = '__main__':
    some1 = Converter()
    some2 = Converter()
    
    x1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=some1.myfunc())
    x2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=some2.myfunc())
    x1.start()
    x2.start()
```

Doing like this keeps running functions consequentially. I have googled a lot but I did not understand if I am doing something wrong in the main body or I have to change something in the class body.

Thank you for the help

Comment: `target=some1.myfunc()` is an immediate call to the function, happening in the main process.  You then launch another process to run the function's return value, which is likely to be None.  Get rid of those parentheses.

Comment: Now it looks working quite fine. Thank you so much @jasonharper